# ng2-select2 disable default value

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I have following setup in my angular project:

`Hello.component.html`

```
<select2
 ngDefaultControl
 [data]="list"
 [options]="{ placeholder: placeholder }"
>
</select2>
```

`Hello.component.ts`

```
list = [
{
  id: 1,
  text: 'Item 1 one'
},
{
  id: 2,
  text: 'Item 2 one'
},
{
  id: 3,
  text: 'Item 3 one'
},
{
  id: 4,
  text: 'Item 4 one'
},
{
  id: 5,
  text: 'Item 5 one'
}]
```

And when my component loads, automatically the first value in 'list' array is selected by default. How can i change default selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ng2-select2 GitHub Repo](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2):

> **value** string: Default value for select 2

Example from the demo:

```
<select2 [data]="exampleData" [value]="startValue" (valueChanged)="changed($event)"></select2>
```

Or in your case:

```
<select2
 ngDefaultControl
 [data]="list"
 [options]="{ placeholder: placeholder }"
 [value]="list[1]"
>
</select2>
```